# Generating classes from multiple wsdls using jaxws-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, wsdl, jaxws-maven-plugin

Im trying to generate classes from multiple WSDLs using `jaxws-maven-plugin`.
But it generates classes only from the wsdl defined in the first execution block.

I have seen this topic has been discussed in several places and i have changed my pom according to the comments. Still i cannot get it work.

```
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>session-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/wsdl/SESSION.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}</bindingDirectory>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <sourceDestDir>${genSrc.directory}</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>api-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFiles>
                                <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/wsdl/STAGE.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            </wsdlFiles>
                            <bindingDirectory>${project.basedir}</bindingDirectory>
                            <keep>true</keep>
                            <sourceDestDir>${genSrc.directory}</sourceDestDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <wsdlDirectory>
                        ${basedir}/
                    </wsdlDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: is above `plugin` block is under `pluginManagement` block?

Comment: Its under plugins block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue here is related to this configuration:

```
<sourceDestDir>${genSrc.directory}</sourceDestDir>
```

Both executions have the same `sourceDestDir`. You should specify 2 different `sourceDestDir`, something like this:

```
<!-- sourceDestDir for the first execution -->
<sourceDestDir>${genSrc.directory}/session</sourceDestDir>

<!-- sourceDestDir for the second execution -->
<sourceDestDir>${genSrc.directory}/stage</sourceDestDir>
```